# Permission Denied copying to (User Data) dir -Haas Next Gen Control

Tags: cnc, lathe, networking

We recently purchased a new Lathe - Haas with Netshare, Next Gen Control. We are copying a file to the Haas Drive's (User Data) folder from a network PC. The problem we're seeing is random and intermittent.

When things are working smoothly we can repeatedly overwrite existing program files on the Haas drive's (User Data) folder without problem. However, occasionally when we try to delete or copy-over the file a Visual Basic (70 Permission Denied) error is displayed on the PC we're copying (from).

To me, it seems that something on the Haas device if holding onto this file, the file in it's (User Data) folder that we're trying to delete or copy over.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

This (URL below) is the error message we're seeing if of any interest
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/permission-denied

Comment: If this is new, then have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: yes, we talked to one on the phone but, wasn't much help.  I'm almost certain the Haas device is occasionally (holding) onto this file making it (locked) but am so out of my element here i can't know with certainty. I'm just the app developer, and since it's my app 'showing the error msg' . .

Comment: What about posting on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The (permission denied) error is being caused by something on the Haas Next Gen control where the Haas device is 'locking' the file. That's my belief at the moment anyway, I just don't know the Haas control at all and don't know how it's used etc. .

Comment: I recently realized that we have another haas machine that does the same thing (creates the 70 Permission Denied) error when trying to copy / overwrite a file that exists on the Haas network drive - and this other machine has had this behavior for a few years. At this 'other machine' the operators have been 'manually deleting' the file on the haas device using the fancy haas panel